# Load medium-sized dataset to neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have a csv of 1.9M rows / 187MB  and it gives me `TransientError: There is not enough memory to perform the current task` when I try to `LOAD CSV` it.

I did increase `dbms.memory.heap.max_size` as error message suggested, setting `initial size` to 4G and `max size` to 32G.

So my question is how much memory do I need to load this, as I understand, not-so-big dataset? Is it even possible with 16G ram home computer?

Much thanks for any help..

Comment: Are you running docker locally? There was a similar issue documented here that seems to be related to docker and neo4j:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/9148

Comment: Please, share your load csv statement.

Comment: @Kyle Burkett thanks, but I'm running neo4j on my local machine, not docker


@Bruno Peres I was using the exact same statement as cybersam showed but without `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` , now adding it solved the problem, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not already specifying `USING PERIODIC COMMIT`, as [indicated by the dev manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data) for your data size, you should. That would allow `LOAD CSV` to process your data in smaller chunks instead of trying to do everything in a single transaction, which is likely why you are running out of memory.

Here is a simple example:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///foo.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Person { name: line[1], address: line[2] });
```